# Batch script - Compare 2 directories of pictures, copy and resize only the non-existing files

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 directories of jpg pictures (about 15.000 files), `%source%` and `%target%`, each with theirs subdirectories:

- `%source%` is the directory where I keep the files in full resolution.
- `%target%` is the directory where I want to keep the same files present in %target%, but resized in certain parameters.

I add files in `%source%` continuously, and I need to "synchronize" the 2 directories a couple of times in a week with a batch file.

I had thought of doing this:

1. Compare `%source%` and `%target%` and find the new files
2. Copy the new files (each one with his subdirectory) in a `%temp_dir%`, or create the full path of the file/files and copy it/them into
3. Resize the files with irfanview
4. Move the resized jpg file from `%temp_dir%` to %target%

What a good way to do this operation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code! we are not going to do your work for you, we are here to help you with specific programming problems you encounter; take a look also [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: Hi aschipfl, I tried some solutions but my knowledge of batch scripting isn't so depth. So far I find only the way to synchronize the directories with robocopy, and how to resize the files. I started the post with my questions not to have a work done by others, but only to see if my approach was correct.

Comment: It is not a matter of knowledge... just show what you have by including the code in your post, describe what it should do and what trouble you have with it; _please write my code for me_ questions are off-topic on SO, but poor experience of an OP not, of course...

Comment: Nono, sorry for my possible equivocal opening, I'm here to learn and not searching for a spoon-fed. Thank you for the advices :)

Comment: Anyway, you should post your attempts ( e. g., the `robocopy` command line you mentioned); you should also state the `i_view32.exe` command line you are going to use; and you should also clarify what to do in case a file is removed from the source location (so the target directory contains an orphaned file)...

Comment: Hi @aschipfl, I posted the last solution below, works very well

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to replace the commented-out commands to fit your needs.

```
set "s=%source%"
set slen=0
:start
    set "s=%s:~1%"
    set /a slen += 1
if defined s goto start

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%S in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%source%"') do (
    set "srcfile=%%S"
    set "file=!srcfile:~%slen%!"
    set "tgtfile=%target%!file!"

    if not exist "!tgtfile!" (
        set "srcdir=%%~dpS"
        set "tgtdir=%target%!srcdir:~%slen%!"
        md "!tgtdir!" 2>nul

        REM   REPLACE THESE COMMANDS
        REM copy "!srcfile!" "!tgtdir!"
        REM resize.exe "!tgtfile!"
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you gordon for your help, I'm trying to understand your code, as I said before I'm not so experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry but at present my limited knowledge of batch scripting doesn't allow me to understand (and consequently adapt/modify) the script kindly created by gordon, that I want to thank again for writing it from scratch.

I reorganized in this way, excluding the temporary directory and using robocopy:

```
@echo off

set source=C:\source
set target=D:\target

robocopy /E /XO /PURGE /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns %source% %target%

for /r "%target%" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    if %%~zf gtr 1048576 (

        irfanview.exe "%%f" /resize_short=1024 /aspectratio /resample /convert="%%f"

    )
)

exit
```

It seems all works perfectly, the script copy (or delete) the differences between %source% and %target% and convert only the jpg files over 1mb of size.
Could it be ok?

Comment: Yes, this seems much simpler than my solution. Even better would be to replace the `robocopy` and `for` with: `for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('robocopy /E /XO /PURGE /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np "%source%" "%target"') do irfanview.exe "%%f" /resize_short=1024 /aspectratio /resample /convert="%%f"`. This will only resize the pictures that have been moved/copied.

Comment: I will check this advice as soon as possible, thanks @gordon

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late, I'm doing this thing in my spare time...

I want to explaint in detail what I'm doing with this script, if it could be useful for someone.
At the moment I have something like 60gb of pictures in a desktop pc, and I want to have some of this pics also in my smartphone, also for work reasons.

The pictures folder in my computer contains 10-11 master directories with its subfolders, but i want to keep in the smartphone only 7-8 folders+subs.

I constantly update and modify the computers folders, and:

- I don't want to use cloud or network-related solutions
- I don't want to manage a lot of GB with a smartphone
- I don't want to manage 7-8-10-15mb .jpg files with a smartphone

Here is my final solution.

```
echo Please insert the smarthpone drive letter
explorer
set /p drive=   

set irfan=C:\path\to\i_view64.exe
set source=C:\my\pics\folder
set target=%drive%:\Pics
set dir1=projects
set dir2=computers
set dir3=stuff
set dir4=etc...

echo Synchronizing directory "%dir1%"...
robocopy /E /XO /PURGE /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif "%source%\%dir1%" "%target%\%dir1%" /xf *.dthumb *.nomedia
for /r "%target%\%dir1%" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    if %%~zf gtr 1048576 (

        echo Resizing file "%%f"
        %irfan% "%%f" /resize_short=1024 /aspectratio /resample /convert="%%f"

    )
)
echo "%dir1%" processing done!

echo Synchronizing directory "%dir2%"...
robocopy /E /XO /PURGE /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif "%source%\%dir2%" "%target%\%dir2%" /xf *.dthumb *.nomedia
for /r "%target%\%dir2%" %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    if %%~zf gtr 1048576 (

        echo Resizing file "%%f"
        %irfan% "%%f" /resize_short=1024 /aspectratio /resample /convert="%%f"

    )
)
echo "%dir2%" processing done!

etc...
```

This solution seems work perfectly for my needs:

- I can manage the drive letter (in case of other memory devices is connected to the pc)
- synchronization only of *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.gif files, and %target% exclusion of Android gallery cache and system files.
  If a file or a folder is deleted in source or in target, no problem
- resize for only 1mb over .jpg files (irfan.exe with these commands resize the short side of the pics at 1024px keeping the proportions
- during the synchronization the smartphone MicroSD space is preserved, with the repeat of the resize operation for every single directory

The only problem is in the Android stock gallery app, which don't show the subfolders in a logical order... I solved this little problem installing QuickPick, an alternative Android gallery which allows an advanced configuration, with the right settings it show the full path of each folder.